# How to structure a grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid, emotion, css-in-js

So I'm having trouble with the following CSS:

```
const Content = styled("div")`
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "contentHeader contentHeader contentHeader"
    "contentItem   contentItem   contentItem"
    "contentItem   contentItem   contentItem";
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr; */
  /* grid-auto-columns: 33px;
  grid-auto-rows: 150px; */
  grid-gap: 10px;
`;

const ContentHeader = styled("h1")`
  grid-area: contentHeader;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: black;
`;

const ContentMain = styled("div")`
  grid-column: 1fr;
  grid-row: 1fr;
  background-color: red;
`;
```

I'm aiming for a layout which has the header on the top left, and then two rows.

The first row would have two columns, and the first item would be larger than the second. The second row would have one item which filled both columns.

Instead I get this:

[image: CSS Example]

I know the issue is likely in my `grid-column` line, but it'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction. Also, I don't understand why I have huge gaps between my header and the coloured grid items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to name each one of your content items in template area:
ex:

```
grid-template-areas:
    "contentHeader contentHeader contentHeader"
    "contentItem1   contentItem1   contentItem2"
    "contentItem3   contentItem3   contentItem3";
```

then in your contentItem1 add this to css:

```
grid-area: contentItem1
```

in contentItem2 div add this to css:

```
grid-area: contentItem2
```

finally in contentItem3 add this to css:

```
grid-area: contentItem3
```

this is css only demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "contentHeader contentHeader contentHeader" "contentItem1   contentItem1   contentItem2" "contentItem3   contentItem3   contentItem3";
  grid-gap: 10px
}

.header {
  grid-area: contentHeader;
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px
}

.item1 {
  grid-area: contentItem1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 150px;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: contentItem2;
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: contentItem3;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue! Just as a follow-up, is there a way to restrict the height of `contentHeader`?